# Как установить библиотеку для Qt с github'a?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, cmake

Пытаюсь скомпилировать эту библиотеку: https://github.com/nitroshare/qhttpengine на Windows для Qt.
Делаю все, как написано в Readme - запускаю `cmake -G "NMake Makefiles" ..` и получаю кучку фатальных ошибок:
`The C compiler "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/cl.exe" is not able to compile a simple test program.`

Дальше идут ошибки nmake -
`NMAKE: fatal error u1077 finished with code "0xffffff"` и `"0x2"`.

Путь к папке bin visual studio прописал в Path, cmake тоже прописан в Path. 
В чем может быть дело? Весь день бьюсь с этим. И как ее использовать после того как скомпилирую?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В консоли, где Вы пытаетесь собирать библиотеку, выполните следующий bat файл:

```
C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/vcvarsall.bat
```

С параметром, который Вам необходим; возможные варианты:

- x86
- amd64
- arm
- x86_arm
- x86_amd64
- amd64_x86
- amd64_arm

Если Вам не нужна экзотика, и Вы теряетесь в выборе, то выбирайте **x86** для 32-х бит, и **x86_amd64** для 64-х.

Выполнение этого bat файла необходимо для того, чтобы настроить все необходимые пути и переменные окружения для сборки. В зависимости от параметра, выбираются разные версии компилятора и библиотек.

Comment: Спасибо, все получилось! А что делает этот bat файл? И вторая часть вопроса, что делать дальше, как ее использовать после компиляции?

Comment: @Nik, bat файл настраивает переменные среды, чтобы всё нашлось. По поводу второй части: 2 вопроса в одном, вообще говоря, нельзя делать. Но, это довольно просто, у Вас на выходе будет `lib` файл; как подключать библиотеку в той или иной среде исполнения, Вы можете посмотреть в гугле.

Comment: Благодарю! И откуда вы все знаете...

Comment: @ixSci Ну так может пояснение про то что делает батник в ответ добавить?

Comment: @ixSci, только вот если бат файл выполнить с параметром х86_amd64 при компиляции выдаются ошибки с кодами 0х2 и 0хffffff. А qt на моей 64 разрядной винде не принимает библиотеку скомпилированную с параметром бат файла х86. (с параметром х86 компилируется нормально)

Comment: @Nik, Вы должны понимать, в какой битности Вы собираете и в какой битности у Вас приложение, также, чтобы собирать с разной битностью, в студии должны присутствовать все компиляторы. У меня MSVS Professional и у меня они все есть, если у Вас бесплатная версия, то, насколько я помню, 64-х битный компилятор там надо ставить отдельно

Comment: @ixSci, у меня установлен VS 2015 Community. В Qt Creator мне доступны такие компиляторы: Desktop Qt 5.7.0 MSVC2015 64 bit(amd 64) и 64bit 2(x86_amd64). А в командной строке библиотека не компилируется с параметром бат файла x86_amd64 - на этапе nmake cl.exe выдает кучу ошибок. А если попробовать подключить библиотеку х86(которая успешно компилируется через nmake) то qt выдает ошибку несоответствия битности. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: @Nik, проблема в битности. Задавайте отдельный вопрос, может кто-то ответит, а ещё лучше — пробуйте разобраться самостоятельно.

Comment: @ixSci так я уже два дня бьюсь, гуглю, пробую - безрезультатно. Это ведь один вопрос.

Comment: @Nik, этот вопрос о том, почему не находит `nmake`, как потом всё это подружить с QtCreator и как установить требуемые дополнения для студии — другой. Вот Вы не хотите создавать новый вопрос, а эти комментарии вижу только я, а у меня совершенно нет сейчас времени Вам помогать, таким образом Вы сами себя лишаете помощи.

Comment: @ixSci, извините. Спасибо за помощь.